# What is meaning of "xmlns:v=urn:schemas-microsoft-com" in HTML5

Tags: xml, html

I happened to find the sentence "xmlns:v=urn:schemas-microsoft-com" as title described

Here is source roughly.

```
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!DOCTYPE html><!--<![endif]-->
<!DOCTYPE html><!--<![endif]-->
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><br>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0,target-densitydpi=device-dpi">
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

As I know xmlns is schema, so to speak metadata.
If some element is available in body section, the metadata of this element exist in "schemas.microsft.com"

If I develop a html page using "microsoft" schema,
all elements used in body section will be referernced by "microsoft"
Or, If I use other schema, examply "google" (I don't know whether this really exist)
all element goes same too.

Here is my question
First,
If I use table tag that exist in "microsoft" and "google" schema together
Will chrome browser interpret context differently?
so comes differnt view?

Second,
If xmlns is omitted
what kind of schema will be used default?

Answer (score 5):

The xmlns:* attributes are namespace definitions. Elements and attributes with the prefix/alias "v" or "o" are part of the respective namespace and not part of HTML. If parsed as HTML < 5 the namespaces will be ignored. In HTML 5 here some constructs for specific namespaces (SVG, MathML), but namespace definitions (the xmlns:* attributes) are ignored.

If parsed as XML the attributes define the namespaces. You have to definitions:

- Alias `v`for `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml` - the [**Vector Markup Language**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_Markup_Language)
- Alias `o` for `urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office` - MS Office Open XML common attributes

XML namespaces allow to mix different XML formats and avoiding conflicts because of element names.

You file might be generated by MS Office (2003) or a user copied content from Office into it. If here are no elements/attributes starting with `v:` or `o:` in your document they don't do anything.

If the client knows a namespace/format it can interpret the elements. Not only a browser but RSS Readers, Calendars, ... If a client does not know a namespace but respects it, it at least knows to ignore the elements/attributes even if they have a name that might be valid in HTML.

Comment: You said that is VML, Vector Marker Language... I can conjecture from this name, it maybe a marker language for two dimension expression.
but, this example I writed down above is not imaginary sample, but real world sample in specific operating system.

This is HTML. Isn't it?
Am I saying ignorant? 

As I know "xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" is exclusive property of MS.

So if competitive company in example Google Chrome doesn't support that namespace, Can chrome interpret this html document?

To conclude, Right, it runs well.

But I don't know HOW?

Comment: It is an old UI markup language from MS. Have you clicked the link?

Comment: Of cource, I read it. thak you for your help. but my asking point is not that but, how to distingish "microsoft_com's test tag" from "tom_com's test tag" from the point of view of browsers. You said browsers are not concerned with namespace  in interpreting. but I'm confused why they do not have relationship

Comment: Because HTML was defined before XML and before XML namespaces. Here is XHTML - the XML version of HTML that supports that additional information. Office or old IEs (<9) can understand VML and make use of the information. The point of this is exactly that different clients can use different informations from a document. A single document can be used by different clients for different use cases. The client makes use of the parts it can use - and ignores the others. Like a users manual in different languages - your read the language you understand and ignore the others.

Comment: In XML, there are namespaces with the purpose of avoiding conflict between possibly different specifications from the view of XML parser. right? I think browsers are parsers too. Is this right too? If so, browser have to distingish differenct specifications. but you are saying they are not related. how can I accept it?

Comment: Browsers have different parsers for HTML and XML (or a parser with different modes). They act differently depending on the content type. But a generator/editor might not know how you send the document out. So it will keep the data be default - better then just removing it.

Comment: Really thanks for your sincere reply. For the purpose of confidence whether I really understand or not, I 'd like to ask again. so... Examply, If Chrome browser try to interpret in specific mode this content, it will understand the namespaces in it, and in another specific mode it can't. Right? and At least in html parsing mode, it will not understand the namespaces, so parser will ignore it. Am I right? thanks

Answer (score 1):

In HTML5 in `text/html` mode it has no meaning. It's an error that is interpreted as an attribute named `xmlns:v` which doesn't do anything.

In XHTML5 (HTML5 in `application/xhtml+xml`) it has same meaning as in XML: it declares that the prefix `v` is for namespace identified by `urn:schemas-microsoft-com`, but a mere declaration of a prefix doesn't do anything visible.

Comment: If xmlns:v doesn't do anything. What are xmlns:v for? Suppose I made a specific namespace "Tom.com". So, If I write down a html page like this. <html xmlns:v="Tom.com"> <v:test> helloworld </v:test> </html> Of course, Tom.com include the definition of "test" tag. Chrome brower, or Safari can interpret this? How? test tag is just I made, it is not fit standard grammar? isn't it?

Comment: @trytop it would sort-of say "it's a `test` tag that belongs to `Tom.com`", but nothing more than this. It's up to the browser to know what that means, but browsers know how to deal with HTML, SVG and MathML, but not `Tom.com`, so they will treat it as an unknown meaningless tag with no functionality.